# Is it possible to enable Cross-Region Automated Backup Replication using AWS PYTHON CDK or at worst Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Summarizing, I'm looking for a way to enable in AWS, automated cross-region backup replication. This is not a question about Multi-AZ databases or Read-Replicas.

I've looked at the documentation and have not seen a way to do this using the Python CDK or at worst CloudFormation.

The overview of the task is [Basic Description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReplicateBackups.html)

The [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/stop-db-instance-automated-backups-replication.html) appears to offer the ability to do this.

I've looked at [Cloud Formation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html) and [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseInstance.html) but did not see this ability.

Comment: You are saying the CLI can and links to boto3. And as I understand it boto3 dosen't do it for cross-region. At least you don't specify any regions in this command.

Comment: @ErikAsplund You are correct. I had the wrong link, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Having researched the documentation thoroughly I have concluded this is not possible with the current offers; as of time of writing.

My solution for this was to implement custom cdk resources

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.custom_resources/AwsCustomResource.html

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/@aws-cdk/custom-resources